# Time and Space complexity When shuffling a list in Python (without using the built-in function)

Tags: python, time-complexity, shuffle, space-complexity

I study Python right now,

I would like to implement a function that accepts a list of integers (assuming that it has N elements)
And prints this list randomly and without repetition.

I tried to use the ideas I read here on the site, and implemented two functions,

I will be glad to understand for each fuction,
what is the time and space complexity?

thanks in advance,

```
import random
def shuffle1(arr):
    for n in range(len(arr) - 1):
        rnd = random.randint(0, (len(arr) - 1))
        val1 = arr[rnd]
        val2 = arr[rnd - 1]

        arr[rnd - 1] = val1
        arr[rnd] = val2

    print(arr)

Arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
shuffle1(Arr1)
```

---

```
import random
def shuffle2(Arr):
    result = []
    while len(Arr) > 0:
        index = random.randrange(0,len(Arr))
        result.append(Arr.pop(index))
    print(result)


Arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
shuffle2(Arr1)
```

Comment: Side note: lists are not arrays so don't call a list `arr`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak 
Thanks for your advice! 
i will change it in my script

Comment: @PM2Ring
Thank you! i will read more about how to use the "tuple assignment" that you adviced

Comment: `a, b = b, a` swaps a & b.

Comment: Also, you should read about the Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Comment: Why not use `random.shuffle()`?

Comment: Joel it's the same as PM 2Ring 's answer

Comment: @Joel
i can't use "random.shuffle()", because the idea is to implement this fuction...

Answer (score 0):

> My assumption (which should be reasonable) is that `random.randint(0, n)` has time complexity proportional to the number of bits in `n`.

Complexity is expressed as a function of the size of the input.
In the first case you have a loop that runs `n` times with `n` being the size of the list and inside you have a `random.randint` call with is linear in the number of bits of the length of the list. You thus have `O(nlogn)`. That is, you do `n` times a `logn` operation.

In the second case you use pop (see [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)) which in the worst case may be `O(k)` with `k<=n`. Hence, the running time is `O(n^2)`. You can think at it as `(n+log(n)+(n-1)+log(n-1)+…+1+log(1))`.
`O(n^2)` is the *worst case*, the *best case* (in which you always pick randomly the last element of the resized list) is `O(nlogn)` (see [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) for more details).

For example, this algorithm has `O(f)` time complexity as the number of iterations is 10^9 no matter what, where `f` is the time complexity of `random.sample()`.

```
import random

def shuffle1(lst):
    for _ in range(1000000000):
        pos1, pos2 = random.sample(range(len(lst)),2) 
        lst[pos1], lst[pos2] = lst[pos2], lst[pos1]
```

Space complexity refers to the size of the working memory needed by the algorithm with respect to the size of the input.
In the first case you use `O(1)` auxiliary space, i.e, just 2 variables to store the values in the 2 positions to be swapped (a constant number). Note that the size of the input list is not considered.
In the second case you construct a new list of size n, thus `O(n)`.